# Run sql Stored procedure within vb6 Error opendatasource

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vb6

I'm trying to use bellow code to insert all records from a access table into sql server table using VB6 ADO connection

```
Set cn = New ADODB.connection
cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=password;Persist Security
Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Kargozini;Data Source=DC"
cn.Open
cn.execute("INSERT INTO TLeavePersonel SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source=D:\Kargozini\arazz\Arazdb.Mdb; 
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MYPASSWORD;' )... TLeavePersonel Rowset_1")
```

But when i run the code the following error occurs:

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
>   [OLE/DB provider returned message: The Microsoft Jet Database Engine Cannot open the file 'D:\Kargozini\arazz\Arazdb.Mdb'. It is already opened exclusively by anothe user, or you need permission to view its data.]

Comment: Check this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306269

Comment: Is the path `D:\Kargozini\arazz\Arazdb.Mdb` accessible to the SQL server? Even though you may be running the code on one server, because you are executing it against a SQL server it will be looking for the 'D' drive on itself. You may have to use a UNC share to access it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are working from MS Access, so you can refer to an SQL Server connection in line in a query:

```
INSERT INTO 
[ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Kargozini;].TLeavePersonel 
SELECT * FROM TLeavePersonel;
```

You will find a suitable ODBC connection string here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/